# How to stop node on contact detection in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-development

I am creating a game where I am shooting a projectile that I want to stop once I detect it hits a target, I have setup the correct category bit masks and contact bit mask. I do not have a collision bit mask as I do not want a collision, I want a full stop.

My code is simple on the contact detection:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    switch (contact.bodyA.node, contact.bodyB.node) {
    case (let dart as DartNode, let point as PointNode), (let point as PointNode, let dart as DartNode):
        dart.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    case (_, _):
        break
    }
}
```

Sometimes, honestly like 30% of the time it seems like setting `isDynamic` is not actually causing the projectile to stop at the contact point and the physics engine continues to apply force for just a bit more. See the attached image where I show an example where the projectile is stop exactly at the point of contact vs where it goes beyond the contact point deeper into my physics body.

Is there something I am missing here and is there a better way to pause a node on contact?

Answer (score 0):

I can only make assumptions without screenshots and much code, bu try to remove eventual actions and use the `velocity` property:

```
 dart.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero
```

Also, if the dart is moving fast, you might want to take a look at `usesPreciseCollisionDetection`, [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520014-usesprecisecollisiondetection).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing many of the details, I had an idea that you could give these nodes names and then use the enumerateChildNodes(with: name) method to reference them when the contact occurs to stop their movement.

`dart.name = "dart"` or `dartNode.name = "dart"`

```
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "dart") { node, stop in 
    node.removeAllActions 
}
```

You could also create a physics category identified as none and then give your nodes a collision bit mask with the category none to be certain it cannot collide with anything.

```
    enum PhysicsCategories: UInt32 {
        case dart = 1
        case point = 2
        case none = 4 
    }
```

Then explicitly say:

`dart.physicsBody.collisionbitmask = PhysicsCategory.none.rawValue`

Also, try the .isPaused method on your Scene.